# Explicit Assignment vs Implicit Assignment

Tags: c++, implicit, explicit

I'm reading a tutorial for C++ but it didn't actually give me a difference (besides syntax) between the two.  Here is a quote from the tutorial.

> You can also assign values to your variables upon declaration. When we
>   assign values to a variable using the assignment operator (equals
>   sign), it’s called an explicit assignment:
>
> ```
> int nValue = 5; // explicit assignment
> ```
>
> You can also assign values to variables using an implicit assignment:
>
> ```
> int nValue(5); // implicit assignment
> ```
>
> Even though implicit assignments look a lot like function calls, the
>   compiler keeps track of which names are variables and which are
>   functions so that they can be resolved properly.

Is there a difference?  Is one more preferred over the other?

Comment: It's not a declaration, it's definition. Ditch that tutorial and [read a decent book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Thinking in C++ is free and available from the author's page.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus:  It is a definition, but that does not mean that it is not a declaration.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: It's supposed to be a tutorial and calling definitions declarations doesn't help to get rid of the confusion between the two. Maybe I'm just cranky today. :P

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus:  Saying that something is not what it in fact is doesn't help to get rid of the confusion either.

Comment: The tutorial in question is this one: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/21-basic-addressing-and-variable-declaration/

Comment: Funny that neither of those are *assignment*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first is preferred with primitive types like `int`; the second with types that have a constructor, because it makes the constructor call explicit.

E.g., if you've defined a `class Foo` that can be constructed from a single `int`, then

```
Foo x(5);
```

is preferred over

```
Foo x = 5;
```

(You need the former syntax anyway when more than one argument is passed, unless you use `Foo x = Foo(5, "hello");` which is plain ugly and looks like `operator=` is being called.)

Comment: Worth mentioning that with construction syntax, you need to be careful about most vexing parses.

Comment: Also note that `Foo x = 5` will only work if `Foo::Foo(int)` is not marked `explicit`.

Comment: ... (continuing with @Vitus comment) and `Foo` copy constructor is accessible.

Answer (score 6):

For primitive types both are equivalent, it is for user defined class types that there is a difference. In both cases the code that gets executed will be the same (after basic optimizations are performed), but the requirements on the types differ if the element from which we are initializing is not of the type that we are constructing.

The *copy-initialization* (`T t = u;`) is equivalent to copy construction from a temporary of type `T` that has been implicitly converted from `u` to `t`. On the other hand *direct-initialization* is equivalent to a direct call to the appropriate constructor.

While in most circumstances there will be no difference, if the constructor that takes the `u` is declared `explicit` or if the *copy-constructor* is inaccessible, then *copy-initialization* will fail:

```
struct A {
   explicit A( int ) {}
};
struct B {
   B( int ) {}
private:
   B( B const & );
};
int main() {
   A a(1);      // ok
   B b(1);      // ok
// A a2 = 1;    // error: cannot convert from int to A
// B b2 = 1;    // error: B( B const & ) is not accessible
}
```

For some historical background, initially primitive types had to be initialized with *copy-initialization*. When *initializer-list*s were added to the language to initialize member attributes from a class, it was decided that primitive types should be initialized with the same syntax that classes to keep the syntax in the initializer list uniform and simple. At the same time allowing the initialization of classes by means of *copy-initialization* makes user defined types closer to primitive types. The differences in the two initialization formats comes naturally: `int a = 5.0;` is processed as a conversion from `5.0` to `int`, and then initialization of `a` from the `int`. The same goes with user defined types: `T u = v;` is processed as conversion from `v` to `T`, and then copy construction of `u` from that converted value.

Answer (score 3):

when you are declaring a variable and initializing it, they are functionally the same in that context. I usually refer to the two as:

```
int nValue = 5; // assignment syntax
```

and

```
int nValue(5); // construction syntax
```

For basic types, I prefer assignment over construction since it is more natural, especially for those who have programmed in other languages.

For class types, I prefer construction syntax since it obviates the existence of a constructor function.

Comment: The standard (N3242) calls the syntaxes `T x = a` *copy-initialization* and `T x(a)` *direct-initialization*. Both are valid ways of invoking the constructor `T::T(a)`.