# why two ways to variable initialization

Tags: c++, variable-initialization

Why C++ gives two ways to initialize variable?

First way is `C-type initialization` where we assign value to the variable at the place where we define it.

`int a = 0;`

Another way, `constructor initialization` which is done by enclosing the initial value between parentheses ().

`int a(0);`

My question is what was reason that the creators of C++ were forced to introduce new way to initialize variable. Although C-style initialization was doing the job.

Comment: You are aware of multi-parameter constructors, right?

Comment: you forgot the third (`{ }`) way :)

Comment: you can start by checking for any explanation in the current (free) working draft of the C++ standard: https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Comment: And the fourth way: `auto i = 0;`

Comment: @TartanLlama That's just type inference, there's no difference in the initialization semantics or syntax.

Comment: @Asad well the syntax is different, and the semantics are different if you pair it with braced initialization.

Comment: @TartanLlama I am stuck with C++98... not much acquainted with C++11/C++14

Comment: @HadeS [this](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/thoughts-on-vagaries-of-c-initialization.html) recent article on the subject by Scott Meyers might interest you.

Comment: Were they "forced" or did they choose?

Comment: @Angew Yes I know about multi-parameter constructor... Kindly elaborate your comment...

Comment: OK then, how would you use a multi-parameter constructor without the direct initialisation (`( )`) syntax? And without (even coinceptually) creating a temporary object?

Comment: @Angew so why this is available for intrinsic types... Point is valid for user-defined types.... or for intrinsic types there is no difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int a = 0;` exists for legacy (and because it feels natural, especially for built-in types), and `int a(0)` exists for explicitness and consistency - there are situations where you may want a more complicated copy constructor which takes multiple arguments or arguments of other types (conversion constructors).

If it can (ie. if the appropriate constructor is available), the compiler will treat both `int a = 0;` and `int a(0)` as a call to the copy constructor. The precise behavior is explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

I think this is because constructors with initializer lists are generally faster, which I *think* has to do with the the fact that the value can be placed into the newly allocated variable memory in fewer memory accessing operations. [Here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists) is a CPP FAQ on that topic (a great website for questions like this, btw).

Comment: You should clarify that your leading statement is a misconception, otherwise you give the impression that it holds true.

Comment: @juanchopanza - yes good point. I've updated my answer to make it a bit more direct.

Comment: I also don't think "the compiler will replace `int a = 0;` with `int a(0);`" is correct. The compiler doesn't have to do that, and the standard doesn't say it has to.

Comment: "Copy initialization is performed in the following situations:
1) when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) of a non-reference type T is declared with the initializer consisting of an equals sign followed by an expression." - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: That doesn't mean the compiler replaces one thing with the other.

Comment: Hm yes you may be right - my wording is off... I don't know that it "replaces" it, but it treats the one as the other.

Comment: I would say they are *functionally equivalent* if the types involved have certain properties, not that they are replaced or treated as one another.

Comment: I guess you could say under certain conditions (which apply to OP's example) the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Basically implicit is the preferred way:

```
int nValue = 5; // explicit initialization

int nValue(5); // implicit initialization
```

Here are some reads:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/21-basic-addressing-and-variable-declaration/

[Explicit Assignment vs Implicit Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751850/explicit-assignment-vs-implicit-assignment)

Comment: The terms `explicit initialization` and `implicit initialization` seem mixed up and imprecise to me. The official terms are copy-initialization and direct-initialization.

Answer (score -4):

When you use the first, what you call C-type initialization, the variable will be written to twice, first the default value and second the assignment, as for the second case it will directly be set to the specified value. I think modern compilers optimize this for primitive types but for objects it could make quite a difference.

Comment: That's not true, copy-initialization never calls the default constructor.

Comment: Check this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: Hmm...how will it avoid calling the default constructor?

Comment: It's still *initialisation,* **not** assignment. When you say `T a = b;`, and `b` is of type `T`, it's the same as `T a(b);` (modulo explicit ctors). When `b` is not of type `T`, it's the same as `T a(T(b));`. No assignment and no default construction.